# Implicit contravariance on classes - simple failed example

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

There are some great resources on [covariance and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962629/contravariance-explained) here on StackOverflow, but I seem to misunderstand the fundamentals of contravariance.  I expect this example to work:

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A a = new B();
        B b = new A();
    }
}

public class A
{
    int id { get; set; }
}
public class B : A
{
}
```

Setting a to B works, which is covariance, but setting b to a new A fails with a compile error.  Even doing an explicit cast still generates error at compile time.  Is there a way to do this or do I just completely misunderstand contravariance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do:

```
B b = new A();
```

Because an `A` simply **isn't** a `B`. The assignment is invalid. I'm not sure I'd even call this variance - it is simply inheritance.

In the general case where B had members that A doesn't, you can see that it makes no sense to do (if `b` actually holds a reference to an `A` object):

```
b.SomeMethod();
```

where SomeMethod is defined only in B, but this logic extends to the assignment to the variable itself. Even if you added a cast, the cast has an implicit type check that would fail.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  So let's say B has string Title in it.  I'd like to assign all members from A to B, then assign Title separately.  Besides explicitly assigning all properties individually, is there a shortcut?  That's all I'm actually after.

Comment: @Doug - AutoMapper maybe ? It also isn't unheard of to use a serialization round-trip to change between alike models, but AutoMapper is probably your easiest option here.

Comment: Great...hadn't heard of the AutoMapper project.  That helps my efficiency but I was thinking the implicit cast would work and keep the runtime efficient.  Anyway, now I know...thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

> do I just completely misunderstand contravariance?

Yes. You have *completely and totally misunderstood what "covariance" and "contravariance" mean*. You have confused them with *assignment compatibility*.

This is an extremely common error. The two concepts are related, but they are **not at all the same**.

**Assignment compatibility** is the property that an expression of one type may be stored in a variable of another type.

**Covariance** is the property that a mapping from types to types preserves the direction assignment compatibility. If Giraffe is assignment compatible with Animal, and this implies that `IEnumerable<Giraffe>` is assignment compatible with `IEnumerable<Animal>` then the `IEnumerable<T>` mapping is *covariant*.

See my article on the subject for more details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx

> Setting a to B works, which is covariance

Yes it works. "a" is *assignment compatible* with B. It is *not* "covariance" because *nothing is varying*. There is no *mapping from types to types* that preserves the direction of assignment compatibility used in the assignment "a = B"; nothing is even generic.

> but setting b to a new A fails with a compile error.

Correct.

> Is there a way to do this ?

No. Instead of "A" and "B", call them Animal and Giraffe. Every Giraffe is an Animal, so if a variable can hold an Animal, then it can hold a Giraffe. If you try to go the other way, you can't put an Animal into a variable of type Giraffe.  The Animal might actually be a Tiger. Why should you be allowed to put a Tiger into a variable of type Giraffe?

Comment: I suspect I'm not reading this correctly. You state "There is no mapping from types to types that preserves the direction of assignment compatibility." What about `T -> IEnumerable<T>`? Then if a `T` is assignable to a variable of type `U`, it is also the case that an `IEnumerable<T>` is assignable to a variable of type `IEnumerable<U>`. Conversely if instances of `T` is not assignable to variables of type `U`, the same will be true of instances of `IEnumerable<T>` for variables of type `IEnumerable<U>`. This seems to be a mapping from types to types that preserves assignment compatibility.

Comment: @Jason: I meant "there is no such mapping used in your program". I've updated the text.

Comment: +1 Thanks! That clears up covariance for me.  I just need to spend some more time working on my contravariance understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Contravariance is not about violating casting rules; it applies in a situation like:

```
void WithApple(Action<Apple> eat);
```

Now, suppose you have some method that knows how to eat any kind of fruit:

```
void EatFruit(Fruit fruit);
```

Since it can eat any kind of fruit, you should be able to say:

```
WithApple(EatFruit);
```

This was not possible before contravariance support, as the delegate had to match exactly.

This is distinct from covariance, which is the slightly more intuitive notion of:

```
void EatAllFruit(IEnumerable<Fruit> inBasket);
```

where you should be able to:

```
IEnumerable<Apple> apples = someBasket;
EatAllFruit(apples);
```