# Why does ReSharper suggest that I make type parameter T contravariant?

Tags: c#, resharper, contravariance

ReSharper suggests me to make type parameter T contravariant by changing this:

```
interface IBusinessValidator<T> where T: IEntity
{
    void Validate(T entity);
}
```

Into this:

```
interface IBusinessValidator<in T> where T: IEntity
{
    void Validate(T entity);
}
```

So what is different between `<T>` and `<in T>`? And what is the purpose of contravariant here?

Let say I have `IEntity`, `Entity`, `User` and `Account` entities. Assuming that both `User` and `Account` have `Name` property that need to be validated.

How can I apply the usage of contravariant in this example?

Comment: Have you already read the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I already read it. However I have a little problem with understanding the article. Anyway, the link helped.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> So what is different between <T> and <in T>?

The difference is that `in T` allows you to pass a more generic (less derived) type than what was specified.

> And what is the purpose of contravariant here?

ReSharper suggests to use contravariance here because it sees the you're passing the `T` parameter **into** the `Validate` method and wants to enable you to broaden the input type by making it less generic.

In general, contravariance is explained to length in [Contravariance explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962629/contravariance-explained) and in [Covariance and contravariance real world example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662369/covariance-and-contravariance-real-world-example), and of course throughout the documentation on MSDN (there is a [great FAQ by the C# team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)).

There is a nice example via MSDN:

```
abstract class Shape
{
    public virtual double Area { get { return 0; }}
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    private double r;
    public Circle(double radius) { r = radius; }
    public double Radius { get { return r; }}
    public override double Area { get { return Math.PI * r * r; }}
}

class ShapeAreaComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<Shape>
{
    int IComparer<Shape>.Compare(Shape a, Shape b) 
    { 
        if (a == null) return b == null ? 0 : -1;
        return b == null ? 1 : a.Area.CompareTo(b.Area);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // You can pass ShapeAreaComparer, which implements IComparer<Shape>, 
        // even though the constructor for SortedSet<Circle> expects  
        // IComparer<Circle>, because type parameter T of IComparer<T> is 
        // contravariant.
        SortedSet<Circle> circlesByArea = 
            new SortedSet<Circle>(new ShapeAreaComparer()) 
                { new Circle(7.2), new Circle(100), null, new Circle(.01) };

        foreach (Circle c in circlesByArea)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c == null ? "null" : "Circle with area " + c.Area);
        }
    }
}
```

> How can I apply the usage of contravariant in this example?

Let's say we have our entities:

```
public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

We also have a `IBusinessManager` interface and a `BusinessManager` implementation, which accepts an `IBusinessValidator`:

```
public interface IBusinessManager<T>
{
    void ManagerStuff(T entityToManage);
}

public class BusinessManager<T> : IBusinessManager<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private readonly IBusinessValidator<T> validator;
    public BusinessManager(IBusinessValidator<T> validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void ManagerStuff(T entityToManage)
    {
        // stuff.
    }
}
```

Now, lets say we created a generic validator for any `IEntity`:

```
public class BusinessValidator<T> : IBusinessValidator<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public void Validate(T entity)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.Name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(entity.Name);
    }
}
```

And now, we want to pass `BusinessManager<User>` an `IBusinessValidator<T>`. Because it is **contravariant**, I can pass it `BusinessValidator<Entity>`.

If we remove the `in` keyword, we get the following error:

[image: Not contravariant]

If we include it, this compiles fine.

Comment: Is it not suggesting because it is declared as void?

Comment: What does void have to do with contravariance? It is suggesting it because he's passing `T` into the method. If it was using it as a return type, it would of suggested `out T`

Comment: So in T or out T is not the main question for which OP seeks answer? And in your example how OP will realate to it?

Comment: The OP asked for the *purpose* of the suggestion.

Comment: I have a little understanding problem with contravariant as well. So I updated the question. An example may help a lot.

Answer (score 5):

To understand ReSharper's motivation, consider [Marcelo Cantos's donkey gobbler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662396/1709587):

> ```
> // Contravariance
> interface IGobbler<in T> {
>     void gobble(T t);
> }
>
> // Since a QuadrupedGobbler can gobble any four-footed
> // creature, it is OK to treat it as a donkey gobbler.
> IGobbler<Donkey> dg = new QuadrupedGobbler();
> dg.gobble(MyDonkey());
> ```

If Marcelo had forgotten to use the `in` keyword in the declaration of his `IGobbler` interface, then C#'s type system wouldn't recognise his `QuadrupedGobbler` as a donkey gobbler, and so this assignment from the code above would fail to compile:

```
IGobbler<Donkey> dg = new QuadrupedGobbler();
```

Note that this wouldn't stop the `QuadrupedGobbler` from gobbling donkeys - for instance, the following code *would* work:

```
IGobbler<Quadruped> qg = new QuadrupedGobbler();
qg.gobble(MyDonkey());
```

However, you wouldn't be able to assign a `QuadrupedGobbler` to a variable of type `IGobbler<Donkey>` or pass it to some method's `IGobbler<Donkey>` parameter. This would be weird and inconsistent; if the `QuadrupedGobbler` can gobble donkeys, then doesn't that make it a kind of donkey gobbler? Luckily, ReSharper notices this inconsistency, and if you leave out the `in` in the `IGobbler` declaration, it will suggest that you add it - with the suggestion *"Make type parameter T contravariant"* - allowing a `QuadrupedGobbler` to be used as an `IGobbler<Donkey>`.

In general, the same logic outlined above applies in any case where an interface declaration contains a generic parameter that is only used as the type of method *parameters*, not return types.