# implicitly convert type of Generic Class to its Specific inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I have an abstract data entity `MyDataRow` which inheritance `DataRowA` from it.
There is a generic class which use of it `BusinessRow<TData> where TData:MyDataRow`. Problem is where I want create a new object of BusinessRow depend of a string variable:
 `public BusinessRow<MyDataRow> AddNewRow(string rowType)`
and using one of the inheritance class of MyDataRow in its generic type:

```
public class BusinessRow<TData>
    where TData : MyDataRow
{
}

public abstract class MyDataRow
{
}

public class DataRowA : MyDataRow
{
}

public class Main
{
    public BusinessRow<MyDataRow> AddNewRow(string rowType)
    {
        BusinessRow<MyDataRow> row = null;
        switch (rowType)
        {
            case "A":
            default:

                row =new BusinessRow<DataRowA>();
// Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 
// 'BusinessRow<DataRowA>' to 'BusinessRow<MyDataRow>' 

                break;
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

at the following code

```
BusinessRow<MyDataRow> row = new BusinessRow<DataRowA>();
```

I get this error

```
Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 
 'BusinessRow<DataRowA>' to 'BusinessRow<MyDataRow>'
```

Comment: Just because `DataRowA : DataRow`, doesn't mean `T<DataRowA> : T<DataRow>`. Your constraint must be *co-variant*, and you must define it on an interface.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962629/contravariance-explained)

Comment: You cannot call the constructor to a DataRow.  The DataRow gets it properties from the parent DataTable.  So a new row is usually obtained from DataRow dr = dt.Rows.Add().  It your code you do not need 'new'.

Comment: @jdweng They are not creating an instance of `DataRow`. And even if they were, they are using their own class named `DataRow`, not part of the standard library.

Comment: Please don't think about System.Data.DataRow or DataTable because I didn't use of System.Data namespace. DataRow is my personal class

Comment: @Rob, But interface does not help. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @Hamid You'll need to create an interface and define it like `interface IDataRow<out TRowType> where TRowType : MyDataRow` and then implement it: `class BusinessRow<TRowType> : IDataRow<TRowType> where TRowType : MyDataRow`, and then return `IBusinessRow<MyDataRow>` instead of `BusinessRow<MyDataRow>`, but you should read up on covariance tutorials / explanations.

Comment: It's a bit complicated!