# Why doesn't generic methods work with inheritance and interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

Okay. I'll be brief. Why doesn't this work ?

```
//Find<T> returns the T object with a given name
//Not a true method, but that's simplier for the example.
Warrior conan = Find<Warrior> ("Conan");
//Debug.Log is just printing the results
Debug.Log (conan is Warrior); //True
Debug.Log (conan is Character); //True, Warrior extends Character
Character other = Find<Character> ("Conan"); // Null, Why ?
```

I guess that generic c# methods are quite differents in IL, and this is why that doesn't work. But it's quite annoying. Am I doing anything wrong ? Is there a way to bypass this ?

EDIT:

In fact, my method is a bit different. I'm using MVC and I want to find the view corresponding to a model.

```
public ElementView<E> Find<E> (E model) {

    ElementView<E>[] tab = gameBoardView.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<ElementView<E>> ();
    foreach (ElementView<E> el in tab)
        if (EqualityComparer<E>.Default.Equals(el.model, model))
            return el;
    return null;
}
```

And I use it like this :

```
ElementView<Warrior> w = Find<Warrior> (myCharacter); // good if my character is a warrior
ElementView<Character> c = Find<Character> (myCharacter); // null
```

Comment: adding the code of Find<T> would help.

Comment: Please show the source of the `Find` method.

Comment: How to ask a good question: [ask] And how to provide good example code: [mcve]

Comment: my bet is that conan.getType() == "Warrior" and Find<Character> breaks on that. It would seem that Find<> needs to use the same `is` check your code is doing here

Comment: To clarify what everybody else is saying: This has nothing to do with generics as such. It's an issue with the implementation of the particular method you're calling. If somebody wrote a `GreaterThanOrEqual(a, b)` method that returned `a == b`, that's not due to the nature of integers, it's due to the nature of whoever wrote the method.

Comment: That could be EqualityComparer<E> which doesn't manage inheritance ?

Comment: Rufus L, I don't really use Find like that. I edited my post and there is an example of my uses at the bottom.

Comment: C# support variance only for interfaces and delegates, thus class `ElementView<Warrior>` is **not** subclass of `ElementView<Character>`.

Comment: How should I do then ?

Comment: Do you know what *covariance and contravariance* is? If not, learn that first. The key insight is: a bowl of apples cannot be used as a bowl of fruit: you can put a banana into a bowl of fruit but not into a bowl of apples. A bowl of fruit cannot be used as a bowl of apples because you can take a banana *out* of a bowl of fruit, but not out of a bowl of apples.  Therefore bowls are *neither contravariant nor covariant*. In C# interfaces and delegates *might* be covariant or contravariant, but classes and structs *never* are.

Comment: How have you implemented equality for `Character`?

Comment: I didn't. They are equals if they have the same reference.

Comment: I think the problem isn't equality, but that ElementView<Warrior> is not subclass of ElementView<Character>. Is there any way to bypass that ?

Comment: @F.Morival: **Read my comment**. If you understood covariance and contravariance then you would know the answer to your question. Take this opportunity to learn about it, since it is the crux of your problem.

Comment: You should probably also read my series of articles about "wizards and warriors", as it is directly germane to your business logic here.

Comment: Have you tried `Character other = Find<Warrior>("Conan")` ?

Comment: @DavidRTribble: his method is returning `null`. Assigning that `null` to a variable of a different type isn't going to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, you could probably answer this question yourself, if you would study variance in generic type parameters. Recommended reading includes:

[In C#, why can't a List object be stored in a List variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6557)
[C# variance problem: Assigning List as List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033912)
[Contravariance explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1962629)
[Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184551)
Eric Lippert's [Wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) series (this link is to part 1)

That said, in an effort to address your immediate concern and to possibly provide some practical, actionable information…

Your method breaks here:

```
ElementView<E>[] tab = gameBoardView.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<ElementView<E>> ();
```

Specifically, the type of the `model` is `Warrior`, which will have an instance of `ElementView<Warrior>` in the collection being searched by `GetComponentsInChildren<T>()`. When you call `Find<Character>()`, you call the generic method `GetComponentsInChildren<Character>()`, which will search for instances of `ElementView<Character>`.

Since `ElementView<Warrior>` is not an `ElementView<Character>` — that is, it doesn't inherit that type — it is excluded from the search. The search would return *only* instances of `ElementView<Character>`, which will not include the view for the model in question. (The returned collection may in fact be empty, if `Character` is simply the base class used by all of the real types…only if there are actual `ElementView<Character>` objects in the components collection would you even get any objects returned by the method.)

Whether you can do anything about this depends on the type `ElementView<T>` and whether you are able to introduce an interface type into your code to represent `ElementView<T>` objects. That is, it would be legal for `GetComponentsInChildren<T>()` to return objects of type `ElementView<Warrior>` when you ask for objects of type `ElementView<Character>` only if:

1. You can change the code to return a collection of interface types instead of `ElementView<T>` types (e.g. `IElementView<T>`), and
2. The interface's type parameter `T` can be declared as covariant; that is, with the `out` keyword, indicating that all members of the interface only ever *return* objects of type `T`, and not accept them as parameters.

If those things were true, then you could declare the appropriate interface, make sure that `ElementView<T>` implements that interface, and then objects of type `ElementView<Warrior>` could be cast to the interface type `IElementView<Character>`. Since the interface type parameter would be `Character`, and the interface implementation could only return objects of type `Character`, the fact that the object is actually returning an object of type `Warrior` would be fine. `Warrior` is (presumably) a `Character`, and so returning a `Warrior` satisfies the interface's declaration of returning `Character` values.

If you could meet those requirements, then the `GetComponentsInChildren<T>()` method could return an array of type `IElementView<T>[]`, which could in fact contain your object of interest that is actually type `ElementView<U>` where `U` inherits `T` (i.e. `GetComponentsInChildren<Character>()` would return `IElementView<Character>[]`, in which it would be valid to find an instance of `IElementView<Warrior>`).

Of course, you'd also need to change the code that uses these types, including `GetComponentsInChildren<T>()` (depending on its implementation). It's not a simple "throw the switch" kind of change to support variance in your generic types. But assuming your types are compatible with variant declarations, it can be a worthwhile effort.

I can't provide any specific advice on how exactly those changes would be made, or even if they are possible, since your question does not include a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want to make these changes, I recommend you study variance first, then make an effort on your own to change the code. If you still have trouble after that, post a new question, being sure to include a good MCVE showing clearly what you're trying to do, and explain precisely what it is you're still having trouble with.