# Problem with adding items to a generic list

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following interface

```
public interface IInterface
{
    int GetId();
}
```

ClassA is a generic class but T should implement IInterface

```
public class ClassA<T> where T : IInterface {

}
```

ClassB implements IInterface

```
public class ClassB : IInterface {
    public int GetId() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

ClassC is where my problem is, namely adding items to the list.

```
public class ClassC {
    List<ClassA<IInterface>> list = new List<ClassA<IInterface>>();    

    public void Add<T>(ClassA<T> item) where T : IInterface {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The code above gives the following error which makes sense

```
cannot convert from 'Program.ClassA<T>' to'Program.ClassA<Program.IInterface>'
```

The core of the problem is in the Add() method where my goal is to be able to add any type of ClassA. I am not sure how to design this in order to achieve the following

```
ClassC classC = new ClassC();
ClassA<ClassB> classA = new ClassA<ClassB>();
classC.Add(classA);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @user3170354.
Why is the `Add()` method generic? The list itself is defined to use `IInterface`. So I think it would be save to make it `public void Add(ClassA<IInterface> item)`.
Maybe that works?

Comment: Generics and inheritance/interfaces don't tend to mix well. Just because `A` implements or inherits from `B`, that does not make `G<A>` have the same relationship with `G<B>`. In some circumstances, co- and contra-variance can help out but this doesn't look like one of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymorphic Type Parameters in Generic Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952546/polymorphic-type-parameters-in-generic-collections)

Comment: Also related: [“Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184551), [“Contravariance explained”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1962629)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using Covariant Generic Type Argument.

```
public interface IInterface
{
    int GetId();
}

// Contra-variant and covariant generic type argument can be used only in interfaces and delegates
public interface IClassA<out T> where T : IInterface 
{
}

public class ClassA<T> : IClassA<IInterface> where T : IInterface { }

public class ClassB : IInterface
{
    public int GetId()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class ClassC
{
    List<IClassA<IInterface>> list = new List<IClassA<IInterface>>();

    public void Add(IClassA<IInterface> item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        ClassC classC = new ClassC();
        ClassA<ClassB> classA = new ClassA<ClassB>();
        classC.Add(classA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: It's actually [Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) not contravariance. (I often have to check to make sure I've got them the right way around too)

Comment: Those names are confusing

Comment: Eric Lippert did a good [series on it back in 2007](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/page/3/). Part one describe why one is `co-` and the other `contra-` at a very high level but it still doesn't make it easy (for me) to see it when I'm working with real C# code. If you haven't read the series before (or want a refresh on it) I'd recommend it.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that out. Also Jeffrey Richter explains this concept in his book "CLR via C#". I may have to reread that part because it is still not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specifics of your design, you may be able to split `ClassA` in two:

```
public abstract class ClassA {
  //Stuff that only works in terms of IInterface,
  //maybe with some abstract methods, required constructors, etc
}
public class ClassA<T> : ClassA where T : IInterface {
  //Stuff specific to T
}
```

You then store `ClassA`s in your list and cast them to their known concrete type as/when you know what that is and need to work in those terms (e.g. to be able to call `ClassA<T>` specific functionality)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I went with @Darkhan's solution of using Contra-variant Generic Type Argument instead to avoid casting.

Comment: Yeah, it works as long as you can fit within the confines of what covariance implies.